# Does running IPython/Jupyter Notebook affect the speed of the program?

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am developing a program for simulation (kind of like numerical solver). I am developing it in an ipython notebook. I am wondering if the speed of the code running in the notebook is the same as the speed of the code running from terminal ?

Would browser memory or overhead from notebook and stuff like that makes code run slower in notebook compared to native run from the terminal?

Comment: Ironically, IPython comes with a `%timeit` magic command that makes this stuff incredibly easy to test.

Comment: A major factor would be whether your program is executing completely in python or calling into C libraries. For example, if the program spends 90% of the time crunching in C, it wouldn't make much difference what the language was. In my experience, python programs can greatly benefit from multiprocessing but see https://medium.com/@grvsinghal/speed-up-your-python-code-using-multiprocessing-on-windows-and-jupyter-or-ipython-2714b49d6fac

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One of the things that might slow things a lot would be if you had **a lot** of print statements in your simulation.

If you run the kernels server and browser on the same machine, assuming your simulation would have used all the cores of your computer, yes using notebook will slow things down. But no more than browsing facebook or Youtube while the simulation is running. Most of the overhead of using IPython is actually when you press shift-enter. In pure python prompt the REPL might react in 100ms, and in IPython 150 or alike. But if you are concern about performance, the overhead of IPython is not the first thing you should be concern about.

Comment: thanks. my simulation is developed in notebook, and the simulation takes about 4 hours to run. I am just wondering if it would speed things up if I  copy the code from notebook into a py file and run it from terminal. Based on your comment it seems there is no need to do that.

Comment: Well having it as a py file have other advantages (importability, running scripts in parallel). If sim takes 4 hours, I would investigate some performance ehancements (cython, multiprocessing, IPython parallel, MPI). Do you have link to what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hi matt. Thanks for your response. The simulation is about sound localization. here is the link if you are interested: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/keithzhou/Localization/blob/master/pc/notebooks/accuracy.ipynb The simulation is at the end of that page (search for "runInParallel"). each run takes about 10min and I need to run a lot of them

Comment: calculate_diff should imho be much better as cython (will clone and try). Is that your repo ?

Comment: See https://github.com/keithzhou/Localization/issues/1, don't use list comprehension on critical loops.

Answer (score 9):

I have found that Jupyter is significantly slower than Ipython, whether or not many print statements are used. Nearly all functions suffer decreased performance, but especially if you are analyzing large dataframes or performing complex calculations, I would stick with Ipython.

Comment: It's just been my experience. Obviously anecdotal,and may be system dependent (running a macbook Pro with el capitan)

Answer (score 5):

I tested learning the same small neural net (1) under Jupyter and (2) running Python under Anaconda prompt (either with `exec(open(foo.py).read())` under python or with `python foo.py` directly under Anaconda prompt).

It takes 107.4 sec or 108.2 sec under Anaconda prompt, and 105.7 sec under Jupyter.

So no, there is no significant difference, and the minor difference is in favor of Jupyter.